# Find control point between two points located on a quadratic curve

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, curve, quadratic

I'm drawing a quadratic curve between two points, and then I locate a random point on that curve. I want to highlight the curved part between the random point and the end point.

So I'm thinking of finding another control point between the random point and the end point, and then draw another quadratic curve with different stroke color on top of the original curve.

Is it possible to find such point or not? Or is there any other way to accomplish this task?

[image]

Here is the piece of code that I'm working on:

```
var startpoint = {x: 50, y: 50}; // Red
var endpoint = {x: 50, y: 250}; // Green
var controlpoint = {x: 100, y: 150}; // Blue

var t = 0.75;
var randompoint = {
    x: (1 - t) * (1 - t) * startpoint.x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * controlpoint.x + t * t * endpoint.x, 
    y: (1 - t) * (1 - t) * startpoint.y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * controlpoint.y + t * t * endpoint.y
}; // Orange


context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(startpoint.x, startpoint.y);
context.quadraticCurveTo(controlpoint.x, controlpoint.y, endpoint.x, endpoint.y);
context.stroke();
```

Here is the working code following answer by [MBo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo)

```
function lerp(a, b, t)
{
    var _t = 1 - t;
    return {
        x: a.x * _t + b.x * t,
        y: a.y * _t + b.y * t
    };
}

var newpoint = lerp(controlpoint, endpoint, t);

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(randompoint.x, randompoint.y);
context.quadraticCurveTo(newpoint.x, newpoint.y, endpoint.x, endpoint.y);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: If you can grab a point that's on the curve between random_point and end_point, then you can use the math here; https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2077533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make new control point for this new curve with simple approach:

```
   P1' = P0 * (1-t) + P1 *  t
```

where P0 is starting point, P1 is control point of old curve, P1' is control point for new curve

(This is particlular case for general Bezier curve subdivision problem)

Comment: Yes, I got it working and also updated the original post to include working code following your answer as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is moving a copy of the curve of between random point and endpoint in the direction of perpendicular to the cure. To find the direction, you can find the line of passing from the random point and endpoint and find the perpendicular line to that line. Hence, moving a copy of the curve in the perpendicular direction as a highlighter.